# Terminal-based calendar on Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, calendar

Is there any Linux terminal-based calendar software available?

Comment: That's what we call "too broad". What features are needed? Anything concerning pricing? Must it be scriptable?

Comment: What is wrong with the `cal` command? See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cal.1.html  As Izzy says, you need to define what you want. The more information that you can give us, the more likely will be to be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

[**calcurse**](http://calcurse.org/) is the perfect solution.

[image: calcurse’s text interface]

To install it, run `sudo apt-get install calcurse`.

Comment: Thanks for contributing, but that's as broad as your question :) What features does it offer? What backends does it support? Can it e.g. deal with CalDAV? What makes it special? Please see our [answer guidelines](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) and improve your post. Just a link and a screenshot don't make an answer here.

Comment: You can also use `ncal`. Just `sudo apt install ncal` and run `ncal`. This'll give u a calendar